# Filter for Multiple File Types

Tags: c#

Using the GetFiles function, how can I go about filtering two (or more) file types?

The code I'm currently using is as follows:

```
            folderlabel1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath; //store 
            string extensions = "*.bsc>*.bs2";
            string[] filterSplit = extensions.Split('>');
            int filtercount = filterSplit.Length;  
            int count = 0;  
            listBox1.Items.Clear();   
            folder1 = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetFullPath(@folderlabel1.Text));   
            for (count = 0; count < filtercount; count++)   
            {  
                fileEntries1 = folder1.GetFiles(filterSplit[count], SearchOption.AllDirectories);  
            }  
            foreach (FileInfo x in fileEntries1)  
            {  
                listBox1.Items.Add(x); //...add to folder display  
            }
```

So I'm trying to filter out both the *.bsc and *.bs2 file types...but obviously the way that it's being done here will just copy the second file type files over the first file types in the array.
I'm wondering:
1. If there is a better way to do this
2. How do you add the contents of one array to the end of another? Is this possible? (because then using this method, I'll store the files in one array and then add them to another, instead of continuously overwriting the one array)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SelectMany` extension method against your filterSplit array to grab the files for each given extension.

```
var fileEntries1 = filterSplit.SelectMany(filter => folder1.GetFiles(filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

This will create an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` that you can then use to assign to your listbox.

For a non-LINQ approach, you could use a `List<FileInfo>` and the `AddRange` method inside of a `foreach` against the array.

```
List<FileInfo> fileInfos = new List<FileInfo>();

foreach (string filter in filterSplit)
{
    fileInfos.AddRange(folder1.GetFiles(filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
}
```

Comment: **var** is not a type.  It is a keyword that you can use to abbreviate local variable declarations that also contain an assignment.  It infers the type of the variable from the expression being assigned to it.  So instead of writing **StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()**, you can write **var sb = new StringBuilder()**.  It is nothing more than a shorthand, what is often called "syntacic sugar."

Comment: thanks everyone, I got it to work! var is an interesting piece of knowledge.